# Console error "Bad Request" with Axios and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm using laravel 5.8 with react and axios. I built a login page and i get a console "bad request" error after login failed. I get the correct response from the server, but i keep getting the a console error of the post request.

Here is the request :

```
 export const getProfile = () => {
 return axios
    .get('api/profile', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
    })
    .then(response => {

        return response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

}

And here is the login function from the UserController

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    $credentials = $request->json()->all();

    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $loginsCount = 0; //init counter

            if ($request->session()->has('userLoginsCount')) {

                //get session value
                $loginsCount = $request->session()->get('userLoginsCount');

                //check login attempts count
                if ($loginsCount == 5) {
                    $current_timestamp = now()->timestamp;
                    Log::info($current_timestamp.' User exceeded alowed 
             login attempts : '.$request->ip());
                    $request->session()->put('userLoginsCount', 0);
                    return;
                } else {
                    //increment it
                    $loginsCount++;
                    // set the new value

                    $request->session()->put('userLoginsCount', 
            $loginsCount);
                }
            } else {
                $request->session()->put('userLoginsCount', $loginsCount);
            }

            //Store session
            Session::save();
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid credentials'], 
     400);

        }
    } catch (JWTExecption $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could not create token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));

 }
```

Api Routes:

```
 Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');
 Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
 Route::get('profile', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
  });
```

Web Routes:

```
 Auth::routes();
 Route::get( '/{path?}', function(){
 return view( 'layouts/app' );
 } )->where('path', '.*');
```

Here pictures of the error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are the steps to fix everything.

**1. Change error response to 401 (not authorized).**

```php
return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid credentials'], 401);
```

**2. Retrieve the error message from the axios error response before use.**

```js
export const getProfile = () => {
return axios
    .get('api/profile', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
    })
    .then(response => {

        return response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {

        // retrieve the error message
        let message = err.response.data.error;
        console.log(message);

        // now you can do something with 'message'
        // ...
    })
```

You were dumping the whole error to the console, not pulling out the actual message.  I'm sorry I overlooked this.

Comment: thanks, i've tried to log the but i'm not getting to the catch, instead of logging the error i get the console errors that i've added in the pictures....i think the error come from the UserConroller in the Login method perhaps i should do something different there

Comment: You absolutely should see console errors when certain things occur (non 200 responses) — this is normal and expected.  However, you should probably be sending a 401 (not authorized) rather than a 400 (bad request) since this is an authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not seeing the `console.log(err)` from the catch statement.  Perhaps try adding `Accept: 'application/json'` to your axios headers.

Comment: Also, let me know if you see the 401 error if you change the value.

Comment: thanks, i'll keep you posted ,i'll get to it in a few hours

Comment: I was able to recreate your issue and I now I believe I fully understand the problem.  I've updated my answer with the two things you need to do to make everything right.  I overlooked the fact that you were dumping the entire error to the console, not retrieving the error message first — that's my bad.  The `catch()` block was in fact firing the `console.log(err)` but the output was not what was expected.